# I can't understand the deleteOwnedPtr function in Webkit

Tags: c++, webkit

In found this function in Webkit

```
template<typename T> inline void deleteOwnedPtr(T* ptr)
{
    typedef char known[sizeof(T) ? 1 : -1];
    if(sizeof(known))
        delete ptr;
}
```

Why they don't use

```
if (sizeof(T))
    delete ptr;
```

What does it mean

```
char known[-1];
```

Comment: my guess is this is supposed to raise compiler errors in some cases.

Comment: Hm, I think it might be this, THX.

Comment: I still don't get it though...

Answer (score 1):

found the explanation in the webkit-dev mailing list. It raises compiler errors if someone is trying to delete incomplete types.

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2010-November/015051.html

> If we delete a pointer and the object has incomplete type, we get
>   undefined behavior. Instead this code causes compilation to fail if
>   the object has incomplete type. The use of a negative number for the
>   size of an array is a way to guarantee we get a compilation error.